# Opening Excel 2007 to a specific worksheet from a file:// link

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Our internal website links to Excel files on a network-mapped drive. The links specify the filename and worksheet to open, in the following format (path and link information omitted):

`ExcelFileName#'SheetName'!$A$1`

This works fine with Excel 2003, but we're moving to Excel 2007, which won't even open the file if that extra information is present.

I haven't been able to find a definitive answer on whether this feature has been removed (or the syntax changed) in 2007. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You should ask this to Microsoft guys. https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=8753&st=1

Comment: @Mepher: SU exists so that questions can be asked. If you don't know the answer, then don't post. -1 if I could.

Comment: @Ben: you've omitted the path and link information, but I think that might be helpful in solving the issue. Can you provide (at least obfuscated) the path and link?

Comment: @guitarthrower: Mehper's comment came a month after this question was initially posted.  suggesting another resource to the asker of a month-old, not-answered question isn't a bad thing.

Comment: @quack quixote: good point. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a VBS script to do this.  Save the following as filename.vbs:

```
Dim xlApp
Dim wbkTemp
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbkTemp= xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\folder\file.xls")
wbkTemp.Worksheets("Sheetname").Activate
xlApp.Visible = True
```

and create a shortcut to this .vbs file.